# PHP contenteditable send form with name

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit, contenteditable

How to use contenteditable in the form. When I submit it, it shown the message "description empty"?
The name must be name="description"

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <table>
        <tr><td>Titulli i postimit</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pëshkrimi</td><td><p name="description" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $description; ?></p></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Krijuar më</td><td><i><?php echo $published; ?></i></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Krijuar nga</td><td><b><?php echo $publisher; ?></b> dhe ndryshimet do të bëhen mbi <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['User'])) { echo "Login!"; } else { echo "$name";} ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Data e ndryshimit</td><td><i><?php echo date('d.m.Y'); ?></i><input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('d.m.Y'); ?>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aktiv</td><td><input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Po" id="pcheck"><label for="pcheck">Po</label><input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Jo" id="ncheck"><label for="ncheck">Jo</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the line im talking about:

```
   <tr><td>Pëshkrimi</td><td><p name="description" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $description; ?></p></td></tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

`<p name="description" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $description; ?></p>`

You can't assign `name` to `<p>` in the manner you desire. Change to `<textarea>`:

`<textarea name="description" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>`

Comment: Thanks but i know this way

Comment: `<p>` cannot, will not, submit values through a form. You can ignore me all you like, but good luck getting this thing to work using `<p>` in your form lol.

Comment: I know allready that <p> doesen't work, I know that textarea works, that works without contenteditable too, I need any tag not a field!! As contenteditable that works like <p> or <span>...